# How to truncate timestamp to minutes?

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, timestamp-arithmetic

I have to subtract 5 minutes from current timestamp and floor(truncate) it to nearest minute. Like '2016-02-23 06:10:39.0' should be '2016-02-23 06:05:00.0'.
I have found way to subtract 5 minutes as

```
 systimestamp - interval '5' minute
```

EDIT 1:
I need timestamp in particular format,

```
 TO_TIMESTAMP((systimestamp - interval '15' minute),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.ff')
```

But this is giving

```
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
```

But I am not able to floor it to nearest minute. 
Please help. Thanks

Comment: select TO_TIMESTAMP(trunc(SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE, 'MI'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.ff') from dual;    This query gives 16-MAR-16 12.00.00.000000000 AM whenever i execute

Comment: `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` data types do not have any format. If you want a formatted value then you need to use `TO_CHAR()` and convert it to string or you can use the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` parameter to set the default format for SQL client. If you want to truncate the date/time then use `TRUNC()`.

Comment: @Jaydeep `TRUNC()` on a `timestamp` will return a `date`. So, if you want the output to be timestamp, then cast the date as timestamp explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. CAST works like a charm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use **TRUNC()** with the precision you want. To trunc only till minutes, use `MI`.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP, trunc(SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE, 'MI') new_tmstmp
  2  FROM dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP                        NEW_TMSTMP
----------------------------------- -------------------
16-MAR-16 04.44.02.379000 PM +05:30 03/16/2016 16:39:00

SQL>
```

Remember, the above output will be a **DATE** and not **TIMESTAMP**. You can explicitly **CAST** the `date` as `timestamp`:

```
SQL> SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP,CAST(trunc(SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE,'MI') AS TIMESTAMP) tm
  2  FROM dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP                        TM
----------------------------------- ------------------------------
16-MAR-16 04.53.25.802000 PM +05:30 2016-03-16 04:48:00.000000

SQL>
```

Comment: Is there any way to cast to a time stamp and retain it's time zone?  So the result would be:  2016-03-16 04:48:00.000000 +05:30 ?

Comment: @shindigo Timestamp doesn't have timezone, you need to explicitly cast it as `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE`. See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/datetime-data-types-and-time-zone-support.html#GUID-C2FD0A7D-974F-4C62-8210-1C356243E222

Answer (score 1):

You can use `trunc()`:

```
trunc(systimestamp - interval '5' minute, 'minute')
```